# Extract rows with repeats, from dataframe where column value matches value from an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, repeat

I have a pandas.Dataframe `df` with one of the column headers being 'X'. Let's say this is of size (N,M). N=3,M=2 in this example:

```
  X Y
0 1 a
1 2 b
2 3 c
```

I have a 1D numpy.array `arr` of size (Q,), that contains values, some of which are repeats. Q=5 in this example:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 2, 2])
```

I would like to create a new pandas.Dataframe `df_op` that contains rows from `df`, where each `row.X` matches an entry from `arr`. This means some rows are extracted more than once, and the resultant `df_op` has size (Q,M). If possible, I would like to keep the same order of entries as in `arr` as well.

```
  X Y
0 1 a
1 2 b
2 3 c
3 2 b
4 2 b
```

Using the usual boolean indexing does not work, because that only picks up unique rows. I would also like to avoid loops if possible, because Q is large.

How can I get `df_op`? Thank you.

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your DF and array and expected output? It would make it much easier to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use indexing to get multiple times the same row:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2]
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 2, 3], 'Y': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

out = df.set_index('X').loc[x].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   X  Y
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
3  2  b
4  2  b
```